# eigenvalues of the sum of a matrix with known eigenvalues and a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $B = A+D$, where all the eigenvalues of $A$ are already known and $D$ is a diagonal matrix, how to compute the eigenvalues of B without diagonalizing $B$ directly?

Comment: If $D$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, easy. Otherwise, no idea.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to know the case when $D$ is only a general diagonal matrix.

Comment: we can look the problem in another way, we know the eigen values of $A$ and since $D$ is diagonal matrix, we also know the eigenvalues of $D$. Knowing eigen values of two matrix, how can we deduce the eigen value of $A+D$. [There is an ambiguity moving from eigen value to matrix]

Comment: @Learner In that case, only when $A$ and $D$ can be diagonalized simultaneously can we add their eigenvalues together to compute that of $B$.

Comment: @Hugo Agreed. Im just repharsing the question to find an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Modulo a similarity, it is like asking: if I know the eigenvalues of $A'$ and if $D'$ is a diagonalizable matrix, what can I say about the eigenvalues of $A'+D'$. Nothing, I'm afraid. The diagonalizable matrices are dense, so the eigenvalues of your matrix $A'+D'$ could be pretty much anything when $D'$ ranges over diagonalizable matrices.